# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{M^k}{k!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does anyone know of a criterion implying

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{M^k}{k!}$$

to converge for positive $M$? One naturally obtains this for Volterra-type equations that I need to do in my functional analysis class.

Comment: Just take the first term of the inner sum ($=1$) and you see that it diverges. (The inner sum is a fast converging approximation of $e^M$).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $M>0$ (if it's a norm you need some inequality, essentially doesn't change)

$$ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{M^k}{k!} < \infty$$

therefore

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{M^k}{k!} = 0 $$

$\frac{1}{1!}$ isn't $0$ though, so no hope.

Can you please post a problem in which this appears? I am studying that and I'm really curious